# Pseudo elements: space between characters

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, letter-spacing

I have a badge that adds brackets via CSS. Unfortunatelly it also adds spaces, is there a way to remove the spaces without a negative margin?
**Current Output:** Items ( 10 ) 
**Desired Output:** Items (10)

```
.badge:before {
  content: '(';
}

.badge:after {
  content: ')';
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djez631j/)**

Comment: You have space in your code remove this and is also working after remove unwanted space around <span>10</span>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It adds spaces because you've got spaces in your markup. There are no spaces if you do this:

```
Items
<span class="badge">10</span>
<hr>
Items (10)
```

Comment: Welp, didn't think the question through. Fortunatelly i was able to change the markup on this one. I'll accept this one!

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces in your html code. Also returns (not <br> but real returns) are displayed as spaces if used inside a text element (like <span>).

```
<span class="badge">10</span>
<hr>
```

should do the job.